# Existe uma forma de substituir os 0 de uma coluna por valores de outra coluna no dataframe no R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Fiz um *merge* de 2 dataframes e percebi depois que tinha 2 colunas que possuem a mesma informação. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
linha qt_funcio nu_funcio ...
1     0         3
2     0         4
3     0         1
4     2         0
5     4         0
6     1         0
```

Queria juntar tudo para nu_funcio e apagar a coluna qt_funcio, sem fazer *mutate* ou somar as colunas. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria-se um vetor lógico para indexar os elementos de `nu_funcio` iguais a zero. E usa-se esse vetor para atribuir os valores de `qt_funcio`. Depois é só remover a coluna a mais.

```
i <- dados$nu_funcio == 0
dados$nu_funcio[i] <- dados$qt_funcio[i]
dados$qt_funcio <- NULL

dados
#  linha nu_funcio
#1     1         3
#2     2         4
#3     3         1
#4     4         2
#5     5         4
#6     6         1
```

---

### Dados em formato `dput`.

```
dados <-
structure(list(linha = 1:6, qt_funcio = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L), 
nu_funcio = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```